# Mongo DB Could not connect to a primary node for replica set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rubymine

This is driving my crazy.

I am starting Mongo in my terminal with:

`mongod`

I am on a OSX mavericks operating system. Mongo is installed, and I have been using it without any issues for quite some time.

Two days ago Mongo worked with no issue. The only change I've made between then and now is I installed Rubymine 6, from Rubymine 5.4.3.2.1.

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
> Could not connect to a primary node for replica set
> #<Moped::Cluster:70318211582520 @seeds=[<Moped::Node resolved_address="127.0.0.1:27017">]>
```

It's happening on this line of code:

```
TempStore.create!(array: array, test_id: id)
```

and `TempStore` is a Mongo Model.

I've seen this error before when Mongo wasn't running, or at least a very similar error. However, Mongo is running and I can't find any reason that this error should be happening.

Any thoughts? I am running rails 4.0.0 and ruby 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the instruction mention in the blog post.[link](http://programminginrubyonrails.blogspot.in/2013/06/mongojsl112-error-couldnt-connect-to.html)

Comment: I tried the above with no success - However, this did lead me to uninstall Mongodb and reinstall it using Homebrew, which worked. Thanks for the help.